# How to create new data types on Lua code?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've searched the web, but no tutorial really made it clear to me, so I need a brief explanation on this:

I want to create new data types for lua (in the **C** language compiler) for creating values like:

```
pos1 = Vector3.new(5, 5, 4) --Represents 3D position

pos2 = CFrame.new(4, 2, 1) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(40), math.rad(20), math.rad(5)) --Represents 3D position AND rotation
```

These are some lines I could ordinary use on a game engine called Roblox. I want to recreate them for using outside Roblox.

Comment: There's no "brief" explanation for how to create objects. There are many ways of doing so in Lua, depending on how serious you are about it.

Comment: Why not using ordinary Lua tables (which are fully accessible from both C and Lua) for your new data types?

Answer (score 1):

```
local Vector3 = {} 
setmetatable(Vector3,{
    __index = Vector3;
    __add = function(a,b) return Vector3:new(a.x+b.x,a.y+b.y,a.z+b.z); end;
    __tostring = function(a) return "("..a.x..','..a.y..','..a.z..")" end
}); --this metatable defines the overloads for tables with this metatable
function Vector3:new(x,y,z) --Vector3 is implicitly assigned to a variable self
    return setmetatable({x=x or 0,y=y or 0,z=z or 0},getmetatable(self)); #create a new table and give it the metatable of Vector3
end 

Vec1 = Vector3:new(1,2,3)
Vec2 = Vector3:new(0,1,1)
print(Vec1+Vec2)
```

Outputs

```
(1,3,4)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

metatables and loadstring are the closes i have come to it in a similar way to this:

```
loadstring([=[function ]=] .. customtype .. [=[.new(...)
return loadstring( [[function() return setmetatable( {...} , {__index = function() return ]] .. ... .. [[ ) end )() end]] ]=] )()
```

This is just the gist of what i mean. Im sorry that its not neat and perfect, but at least its something to go on (i did not sleep much last night).